Test Passed even when I can't find the ID in the file + Save file name
I'm creating automation to validate my files contained in a directory.
My directory has N files. I need to find an ID in my files.
When you find this ID, save the file name and stop searching the rest of the files.
If you don't find the ID in the files, return ERROR, that is, break my test.
Below is my code. In this code I can look for the file, but I can't save the file name and, if I don't find it, the test will break (failed).
cy.task('getFiles', 'batch/22896431000382/uds/processed')
        .then(result => {

          const x = result

          let continue_loop = true
          cy.wrap(continue_loop, { log: false }).as('continue')

          for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            cy.get('@continue', { log: false }).then(continue_loop => {
              if (continue_loop) {
                cy.readFile(`batch/22896431000382/us/processed/${x[i]}`)
                  .then(txt => {

                    // checking for any failed status here
                    if (txt.includes('IdkBGxcJWaapecROrzNh')) {
                      return
                    }
                  })
              }
            })
          }
        });


Why aren't you setting continue_loop?

Does this answer your question? How can I break the for loop within the then block?

As shown in the duplicate question, you would actually need to change the continue_loop variable when you no longer want to ... continue the loop.
let continue_loop = true
cy.wrap(continue_loop, {log:false}).as('continue')   

for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  cy.get('@continue', {log:false}).then(continue_loop => {
    if (continue_loop) {

      ...
      if (txt.includes(...)) {
        continue_loop = false
        cy.wrap(continue_loop, {log:false}).as('continue')

        // save txt for later
        cy.wrap(txt).as('txt')
      }
    }
  })
}

cy.get('@txt').then(txt => {
  // the txt is found!

